# StackOverflow when closing my form

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, stack-overflow

I am trying to close my main(the parent) form when a child form is being closed. However this gives me a StackOverflow exception.

However if I call _child.Dispose on the FormClosed event it works as intended. Should I do this? Why should I call Dispose? (because of the .Show() it shouldn't be neceserry right?

A small demo:

```
public partial class frmChild : Form
{
    public frmChild()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

public partial class frmParent : Form
{
    private frmChild _child;

    public frmParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _child = new frmChild();
        _child.FormClosed += child_FormClosed;
        _child.Show(this);
    }

    void child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //_child.Dispose(); <-- uncomment and it works
        this.Close(); // <-- StackOverflow exception
    }
}
```

**The solution, commented by Teoman Soygul (for future reference):**

> Closing the main form with
>   this.Close(); signals all child
>   windows to close in order so that
>   creates the infinite loop

After calling this.Close() in the parent it will signal all children to Close aswel, which will send another FormClosed event...
I solved it by not specifieing the owner in `_child.Show();` I didn't use the owner anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since every time you call `this.Close();` the `FormClosed` event gets fired which then calls `this.Close();` again, you create an infinite loop. On the other hand, if the form is already disposed (as in you uncomment the dispose line), the `FormClosed` event does not get fired again as the object is already disposed. So disposing of the form on the event is right, or if you don't want to do that, you can add an additional check with a private bool field like:

```
if (!formClosed)
{
  this.formClosed = true;
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Nope, this will give me again a StackOverflowException.

Comment: The FormClosed of child get fired, but if I call close in frmParent then a FormClosed  of the parent get fired (not of the child). So how could this be a infinite loop?

Comment: Closing the main form with `this.Close();` signals all child windows to close in order so that creates the infinite loop.

Comment: @Teoman: +1 Your answer is correct. `Form.Close` by the way doesn't so much as signal child forms to close, it literally calls `Close` on them, giving PoweRoy the infinite loop he is seeing.

Comment: Indeed this is correct, if I call Show(); (without an owner) the problem is not there. Does it have any benifit to specify a owner in this case then?

Comment: I guess so but I didn't try it. If I were designing the event, I would definitely examine the owner to prevent such a loop but you should really check to see if that is the case.

Comment: I've added the solution (ownership problem) to the question for others to see. Your question alone didn't explain enough, the comment was the missing link :)